# Square API + OAuth2: How do I set my redirect URL to my iOS app?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, square, square-connect

I am trying to implement OAuth2 in my iOS app through Square but it's saying there is an error with my redirect_uri when I sign in successfully through the browser that pops up.

[image]

I'm using the OAuthSwift pod. This is what I have so far to set up the URL scheme so that the redirect should open my iOS app:

Square dashboard config:

[image]

AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("hollaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") // i never see this printed
    OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
    return true
  }
}
```

Target:

[image]

Controller that opens the browser:

```
class OAuthViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("tapped");

    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    "my token",
        consumerSecret: "my secret",
        authorizeUrl:   "https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=my_id",
        responseType:   "token"
    )
    oauthswift.authorize(
      withCallbackURL: URL(string: "com.edmund.ios/oauth-callback")!, // doesn't seem to do anything honestly... I think the Square dashboard setting has precedence over this.
      scope: "MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ%20PAYMENTS_READ%20ITEMS_READ%20ORDERS_READ",
      state: "",
      success: { (credential, response, parameters) -> Void in
        print(credential)
      },
      failure: { error in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you guide a user through the oauth flow for your app, you must specify a redirect_uri parameter that matches that value you have specified in the Square developer portal. Note that this redirect_uri must start with http or https and correspond to a webpage on your server.

Comment: i realized that too! so that means there's no way to redirect to my ios app URL. i have to set my callback url to my server, and in that endpoint i need to redirect to my app.

Comment: Is that `http`/`https:` requirement still in place? What about [loopback](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252#section-7.3) and [private use URIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252#section-7.1) as per RFC 8252?

Answer (score 2):

**Redirect to ios app is possible? Completly possible**

Here I will guide you simple approach to achieve this.
The square oAuth implementation can achieve by 2 simple easy steps without using any third-party libraries.

Benefits of this approach

- You always stay within the application (because we use the in-app browser)
- No need to add URI schema in the application (because we never leave the app)

---

- Step 1: Add a view controller and attach a WKWebview;
- Step 2: Load auth request URL and listen for redirect URI;

You can dismiss the controller and proceed with the access token once the redirection happens.

---

**Redirect URI**

You have to set a redirect URI in the square dashboard; 
`(Example: "http://localhost/square-oauth-callback")` 
but you are free to set any valid URL.
We monitor this url within our app.
[image]

---

Implement the following code in your application

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit


class SquareAuthenticationViewController: UIViewController {


    // MARK: Connection Objects
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!



    // MARK: Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureView()
        initiateAuthentication()
    }



    func configureView() {

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }



    func initiateAuthentication() {

        // Validation
        guard let url = getPath() else {
            return
        }

        // Prepare request
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }



    func getPath() -> URL? {

        let clientId = "Your Suare Application Id"
        let scope = ["MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ",
                     "CUSTOMERS_READ",
                     "CUSTOMERS_WRITE",
                     "EMPLOYEES_READ",
                     "EMPLOYEES_WRITE",
                     "ITEMS_READ",
            "PAYMENTS_READ"].joined(separator: " ")
        let queryClientId = URLQueryItem(name: "client_id" , value: clientId.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed))
        let queryScope = URLQueryItem(name: "scope" , value: scope.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed))

        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = "https"
        components.host = "connect.squareup.com"
        components.path = "/oauth2/authorize"
        components.percentEncodedQueryItems = [queryClientId, queryScope]
        return components.url
    }
}



extension SquareAuthenticationViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        // here we handle internally the callback url and call method that call handleOpenURL (not app scheme used)
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url, url.host == "localhost" , url.path == "/square-oauth-callback" {


            print(url)
            print(url.valueOf("code"))
            //decisionHandler(.cancel)

            /*  Dismiss your view controller as normal
                And proceed with OAuth authorization code
                The code you receive here is not the auth token; For auth token you have to make another api call with the code that you received here and you can procced further
             */

            /*
                Auth Process Flow: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/how-it-works#oauth-access-token-management

                Obtain Auth Token: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/oauth-api/obtain-token
             */

        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

}


extension URL {

    func valueOf(_ queryParamaterName: String) -> String? {

        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { return nil }
        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == queryParamaterName })?.value
    }
}
```

Comment: makes sense and yes it was useful though I did it in objective c

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the square endpoint to your server, if your sure they are running on iOS you can use your URL Scheme to reopen your app and pass any parameters that you wish